# Google Sheets: submit button to pass values from Workbook A to Workbook B

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, submit, submit-button

I am new to this and I could use some help.

I am creating a very simple form in which a person will enter data in 4 cells, then press a Submit button for this info to be recorded in a different sheet.

I pretty much got the exact thing I want when it comes to submitting the data to a different Sheet within the same Workbook, however I would need this data to be recorded in a different Workbook altogether.

I have been looking for a solution for some time, but the most similar thing I found are not quite what I need.

The code I have at the moment makes sure all cells are filled, interrupting the code otherwise, copies the info from "Sheet1" to "Sheet2", and clears the cells once it's done. A following submission would continue adding data in the next row.

I would need the exact same thing, but that information on "Sheet1" in "Workbook A" to be sent to "Sheet2" in "Workbook B"

Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
//Clear form
function ClearF(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Form");

  var rangesToClear = ["E8", "H8", "K8", "N8"];
   for (var i=0; i<rangesToClear.length; i++) {
     formS.getRange(rangesToClear[i]).clearContent();
   }
}
//----------------------------------------------------
//Input values for Agent Form
function SubmitHours() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Form");
  var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("Database");

  var values = [[formS.getRange("E8").getValue(),
                 formS.getRange("N8").getValue(),
                 formS.getRange("H8").getValue(),
                 formS.getRange("K8").getValue()]];

if (values[0].some(val => val === '')) {throw new Error ("REQUIRED FIELD IS EMPTY");
return;
}
dataS.getRange(dataS.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 4).setValues(values);
Browser.msgBox("We got it. Thanks!");

ClearF();
}
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: With your solution, two people filling the form at the same time would see what the other person is typing. With Google Forms, you can design the form and the data is added to google sheets when they submit it it. So it is better to use Google Forms in most cases.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Google Forms wouldn't work for me for other reasons. I know workarounds to my issue and other ways to achieve the same goal, but I would prefer if the submit button was able to send the information to a different Workbook altogether.

Comment: okay so when you are using .getActiveSpreadsheet(); you get the active spreadsheet. But you can open any other spreadsheet with .openById() and the rest of the script would be the same. See how to use it in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid

Comment: I was trying to use .openById(), but was completely useless on how to do it. That's when I decided to ask here. You have been very helpful, thanks a bunch! I will have a deeper look into that info you passed me. Have a great one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Submit and Clear

```
function SubmitHours() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const fsh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.ssid);
  const dsh = dss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const rgl = fsh.getRangeList(["E8","N8","H8","K8"]);
  let vs = rgl.getRanges().map(r => !r.isBlank()?r.getValue():null).filter(e => e);
  if (vs.length == rgl.getRanges().length) {
    dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 4).setValues([vs]);
    rgl.getRanges().forEach(r => r.clearContent());
  } else {
    ss.toast("Incomplete Data");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cooper, that works beautifully!